# Read Sim Contacts in Android Programmatically?

Tags: android, android-contacts, android-contentresolver, sim-card

How can I read my Sim contacts in android device  SIM1 and SIM2 separately.

for reading sim1 contacts Uri path is "content://icc/adn".

But to read sim2 contacts how can I provide the Uri.

Answer (score -1):

Android platforms did not have support for multiple SIMs. A device with such support has been customized by the manufacturer and the implementation is thus vendor specific.

Starting with Android 5.1, [multisim support](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-5.1.html#multisim) has been added.

Here is [hack](http://wenda.io/questions/362062/detect-the-status-of-two-sim-cards-in-a-dual-sim-android-phone.html) for older versions which should be vendor independent.